# Batch File to detect active Partitions/Drives

Tags: batch-file, converters

I am working on another batch script to detect active drive letters.
Firstly a theoretical problem, would this also detect or attempt to mount/connect to CD Drives? If so then how do I make it so that it picks drives/partitions only (excluding USB's) and at that how would I make it pick MULTIPLE partitions.

The second issue is that it always picks the very last letter as the drive,
For example, this will pick drive 'Z'. If I remove the letter Z then it will pick drive Y and so on.

```
@echo off 
:main
cls
set "LW=" 
FOR %%I in (D E F G H I J K L M N O P Q R S T U V W X Y Z) DO SET "LW=%%I" 
if defined LW ( 
echo *************************** 
echo * External drive is: %LW% * 
echo *************************** 
) ELSE ( 
echo ************************** 
echo * no external disk found * 
echo ************************** 
) 
echo.
echo Task
echo *************************** 
echo 1: Transfer from Partition 2 to Partition 1
echo 2: Transfer from Backup Folder to Partition 2
echo 3: Exit
echo *************************** 
echo.
set /p task=Pick Task: 

if %task%==1 (
    mkdir "%Userprofile%\Desktop\Second Partition"
    xcopy "%LW%:\*" "%Userprofile%\Desktop\Second Partition" /s /i /y /e
    echo Operation completed successfully
    pause
    goto eof
)
if %task%==2 (
    xcopy "%Userprofile%\Desktop\Second Partition\*" %LW%:\ /s /i /y /e
    echo Operation completed successfully
    pause
    goto eof
)
if %task%==3 (
    exit
)
if not "%task%"=="" (
echo Invalid Selection 
pause 
cls
goto main 
)
:eof
exit
```

Comment: what are MULTIPLE partitions? And what do you mean with `to pick them` ?

Comment: To elaborate further, if there are three partitions or disks in the computer then this batch fill select all of them as %LW% or multiple variables, then with that it will copy the data from %LW% and other variables in to %Userprofile%\Desktop\Second Partition". By "picking" I mean setting the drive letter as the variable %LW% for usage in the %task% function. Manually setting the drive letter will not work as it will be used on multiple machines so the active drive must be picked automatically from this script.

Comment: if you have 'volumes' with a volume letter like 'D:', why do you need to know sth. about 'partitions' in the physical HDD '0'?

Comment: This batch file will be used as a technical solution to data backup. For reasons I cannot explain due to company policy, we require a script such as this one I quickly created to transfer data from partitions (regardless of whether it is on the same drive or not) to the created folder on the MAIN systems partition in %Userprofiles%\Desktop\Second Partition. The issues I am having with this script as stated is that it ALWAYS picks drive letter Z even if it doesn't exist.

Comment: I think you're confusing partition and volume.

Comment: I am not confusing partition and volume, even so that would not make a difference because volumes and partitions are all assigned the same letter within windows. Please re-read everything I have posted as I have explained as best as I can.

Comment: OK I can see now what you mean. To get valid drive letters simply use `fsutil fsinfo drives`.

Comment: Now using the above statements, how could I make it so that the batch will pick one partition/drive letter if it is there, or if there are two partitions then it would pick both partitions (excluding the C: System partition) and save in to the %LW% variable or two variable.

Comment: OK, like you want :), please [here](http://pastebin.com/TNR68naL) is your code.

Comment: Thank for the code, it is now detecting the correct drives however it is still setting drive letter Z as a variable, which then returns the error "File Not Found" despite the fact that there are active partitions with files and folders to copy.

Comment: `if defined` tests for a defined variable, NOT an existing drive.

Comment: My apologies for the late reply. The purpose of the `FOR %%I in (D E F G H I J K L M N O P Q R S T U V W X Y Z) DO ( SET "LW=%%I" )` section is to detect which drives are active, however it always pick Z, with your update though it picks W X Y Z which do not exist on my pc. Is it possible to do what I am looking for? By that I mean is it possible for a dynamic batch script that will detect all of the connected drives by their letter so that one could back up from detected drives to a pre-defined location such as %Userprofile%\Desktop\Second location?

Comment: To detect all connected drives (fixed, USB, CD, LAN ...) you can use the command `fsutil fsinfo drives`. I posted this in a comment already.

Answer (score 0):

Give this a go - and if it works then parse out the 'Fixed disks"

```
@echo off
for /f "tokens=1,*" %%a in ('fsutil fsinfo drives ^| find ":" ') do (
for %%c in (%%b) do fsutil fsinfo drivetype %%c
)
pause
```